# How to enable preview in notifications on an Oppo phone

Tags: notifications, oppo-coloros

I recently started using an Oppo A77 phone and have no experience with ColorOs. All I am trying to do is to be able to display a preview (sender/subject/body/something) show up on my notification window where Gmails notifications come up. There is no option to select preview messages in the notifications settings. 
This is my notification setting for gmail:

[image]

and this is how my gmail notifications come up:

[image]

How do I get a preview of my gmail notifications on an oppo A77 ?

This is the exact question asked on other sites and no one seems to know the answer :

- http://www.androidauthority.com/community/threads/how-to-get-expanded-notifications-in-a77.47010/#post-110606
- http://community.oppo.com/en/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=55040&page=1#pid577510

Answer (score -1):

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

I think I found the answer. I was also looking for the answer because I also wanted to expand my notifications and I tried it and it works.

Comment: This doesn't work on Oppo A77

Comment: Pinch or scroll using two fingers

Answer (score -1):

Deactivate applock for wtsap etc.. And you will get the preview... Confirmed ..

Goto "settings" "app encryption" and "unlock" the apps you want to preview.

Comment: What makes you assume OP uses that applock app? I see no indications for this.